# Esper repeat pattern

Tags: esper

I would like to fire a pattern with the following syntax.

```
EPStatement raiseStmt = cepAdm.createEPL("[1] Event");
```

But i am getting the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" com.espertech.esper.client.EPStatementSyntaxException: Incorrect syntax near '[' [[1] Event]
    at com.espertech.esper.epl.parse.ExceptionConvertor.convertStatement(ExceptionConvertor.java:47)
    at com.espertech.esper.epl.parse.ParseHelper.parse(ParseHelper.java:112)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPAdministratorHelper.compileEPL(EPAdministratorHelper.java:99)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPAdministratorHelper.compileEPL(EPAdministratorHelper.java:71)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPAdministratorImpl.createEPLStmt(EPAdministratorImpl.java:116)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPAdministratorImpl.createEPL(EPAdministratorImpl.java:66)
    at exampleMain.main(exampleMain.java:202)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "admin.createEPL" method takes an EPL statement and not just a pattern. For example "select * from pattern[[1] Event]". 
This is equivalent to: admin.createPattern("[1] Event")

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked for me. i was trying without select keyword.

Comment: I am a newbie to Esper i stuck with the following statement.I have tried select * from pattern too .But it did not work for me.Please provide some pointers for the same.                                                            val Stmt:EPStatement=cepAdm.createEPL("[((every a=Event(alarmCode=12)) while (a.size = 5)) where timer:within(20 sec)]")                                                                 i would like to fire this stmt when there are 5 events in 20 sec.

Comment: My suggestion is to ask the Esper user mailing list to help you design this out.

Comment: Could you provide me the mail Id.I have tried in google but not found.It would be great even if you could provide some pointers to resolve the issue.

Comment: The link for the user mailing list info is link http://esper.codehaus.org/about/esper/mailinglist.html